# Oracle 12cR2 - Upgrade Catalog Command Taking Too Much Time

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, windows-server, rman, patching

I patched my database (Windows database bundle patch 12.2.0.1.201020 (31654782)).

There are 6 instances on the server. After the patch, the UPGRADE CATALOG command I ran on RMAN for the first 5 instances was compiled in 2-3 minutes each. But it has been going on for 1 hour for the last intance. Is there a way to speed it up or is it a bug?

Best regards,

Comment: I don't know why it's running long, but you only need to UPGRADE catalog once.  The rman catalog is just a schema, functionally no different than any other application schema. Once it's upgraded, it's upgraded. No need to repeat for each database.  It just has to be upgraded to match the highest version of any rman client that will be connecting to it.

Comment: Hi @EdStevens, thank you for your comment. I solved the problem. The cause of the error was related to a disk size on the server where the catalog database is located, causing a problem as the recovery area was full, the command was compiled a few seconds after the first intervention. But I have a question, when I use the upgrade catalog command for each instance I get the notification "Recover catalog upgraded to version 12.02.00.01". If it was what you said, shouldn't I get a notification like "Already upgraded"? Best regards.

Comment: One would hope that it would report 'already upgraded', but no it doesn't.  Remember, the catalog is simply a schema. No different than any application schema.  If you upgrade your application, you only upgrade its schema once. You don't upgrade again just because you install another copy of the appliction.  And as far as rman is concerned, the application we are talking about here is rman, not your databases.

Comment: Thank you for informations @EdStevens, you always help me.